# Winform communicate with UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, uwp

I have a winform program, now I need to enhance feature communicate with UWP app, so I added reference Windows.DLL and did some change for winform program, now I can call UWP app thru the method **Launcher.LaunchUriAsync()**, but any an exception on method **Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync()**,

Could you provide me some advice? Thanks in advance.

**Exception:**
The operation identifier is not valid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800710DD)

**Some Code:**

```
   // The protocol handled by the launched app
    Uri testAppUri = new Uri("etrace.scanner:"); 
    var supportStatus = await Launcher.QueryUriSupportAsync(testAppUri, LaunchQuerySupportType.Uri, "80a2fbc7-843e-46ca-a740-cbb1bc604d33_y890260wv9vv0");
    if (supportStatus != LaunchQuerySupportStatus.Available)
    {
        // Check the app available or not.
    }

    var inputData = new ValueSet();
    inputData["TestData"] = "Test data";
    var optionsE = new LauncherOptions { TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "80a2fbc7-843e-46ca-a740-cbb1bc604d33_y890260wv9vv0"  };
    // Call APP successully.
    bool success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(testAppUri, optionsE, inputData);
    Debug.WriteLine(success);

    // Got an exception: 
    var result = await Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync(testAppUri, optionsE, inputData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppServiceConnections.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service

They're for communication with other apps for UWP and they're supported in Win32 and work the same.